# G Suite says to use five MX records but my DNS host (123-Reg) only allows me to enter one

Tags: dns, email, mx, google-workspace, 123-reg

I'm trying to change the MX records for my domain (with 123-Reg) so that it points to my G Suite email.

I have the following MX records from Google's support page:
[image]

But in my 123-Reg control panel, there is only one input field... so I've just assumed that I should use the value from the first row in the table... do I not need to input each of the MX records?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently on the "Basic DNS" tab. Change to the "Advanced DNS" tab and you can then add any number of `MX` records (and any other type of DNS records).

[image: Advanced DNS tab]

Reference:

- https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/domains/how-do-i-set-up-my-domain-name-to-point-to-my-own-mail-server/